# Eclipse is not seeing restored files from Git when I switch branches

Tags: java, eclipse, git, commit, delete-file

I have three branches in my project on Git and I saved the last stable version of my project to the `master` branch before using the other two branches to do a major rewrite/refactor. In the rewrite and refactor I deleted 5 files (JAVA classes) that used to be in the stable program. Now when I switch branches back to `master` those files are missing from the most recent commit to the `master` branch as well, yet I've not merged the branches. How can this be, and how do I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I just discovered that Git is working properly because the deleted files are restored to the folder when I switch to the master branch. The problem appears to be that Eclipse does not see them. This is curious, as I even restarted Eclipse thinking that might be the problem, but even then Eclipse didn't see the restored files. Could it be related to the Eclipse bug mentioned [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=345002)? I'll keep puzzling this out, and am up for a nudge in the right direction if anyone has one!

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse try synchronize workspace.

Make sure files are not open, like no application should be running (tomcat, jetty, djano or something) accessing your work tree.

Try restarting eclipse once. I have seen this problem even outside eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @forvaidya - where do I find the synchronize workspace option in Eclipse?